Vocab size tensors index out of range
I am trying to create a tensor (vocab_size x vocab_size) for a llm, I am using the tiktoken module. But the problem is that when I create the tensor the indices are out of range. The vocab size I am using is the vocab in the text rather than the entire vocab size of tiktoken as the tensor would be much too large:
encoding = tk.get_encoding('p50k_base')
encoded_text = encoding.encode(text)
vocab_size =  len(set(encoded_text))

data = torch.tensor(encoded_text, dtype=torch.long)

num = int(len(data) * 0.9)
train = data[:num]
test = data[num:]

block_size = 8
batch_size = 4

x = train[:block_size]
y = train[1:block_size+1]
for t in range(block_size):
    context = x[:t+1]
    target = y[t]

def get_batch(block_size, batch_size):
    ix = torch.randint(len(data) - block_size, (batch_size,))
    x = torch.stack([data[i:i+block_size] for i in ix])
    y = torch.stack([data[i+1: i+block_size+1] for i in ix])
    return x, y

xb, yb = get_batch(block_size, batch_size)

class BigramLanguageModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.token_embedding_table = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, idx, targets=None):
        print(idx)
        logits = self.token_embedding_table(idx)

        if targets is None:
            loss = None
        else:
            B,T,C = logits.shape
            logits = logits.view(B*T, C)
            targets = targets.view(B*T)
            loss = F.cross_entropy(logits, targets)
    
        return logits, loss
    def generate(self, idx, max_new_tokens):
        logits, loss = self(idx)
        logits = logits[:, -1, :]
        probs = F.softmax(logits, dim=-1)
        idx_next = torch.multinomial(probs, num_samples=1)
        idx = torch.cat((idx, idx_next), dim=1,)

        return idx

I tried to use the function n_vocab but this returns the whole vocab size for tiktoken rather than my text and creates a massive tensor. But it does solve the index problem.
